# Magento 2 -Limit the length of the product name on the front end.

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, php, product-grid

I want to limit the length of the product name on the front end. I have the following code in the list.phtml

```
<a class="product-item-link" href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_product->getProductUrl() ?>">
<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></a>
```

How I can limit the product name to 50 characters for example?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use like below sample code.

```
<?php
$productName = $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name');
$len = strlen($productName);
?>
<a class="product-item-link" href="<?php echo /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_product->getProductUrl() ?>">
    <?php echo substr($productName,0,50); ?>
    <?php if($len > 50) echo '...'; ?>
</a>
```

**substr** function will truncate product name (string)

Comment: thank you how I can put some characters at the end of the name for example ....

Comment: you can count string. for example if greater than 100 then print '...' after product name.

Comment: can you add this in your answer please?

Comment: added. please check

Comment: How this can be done in admin grid?

Answer (score 2):

Try below code

```
<a class="product-item-link" href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_product->getProductUrl() ?>">
    <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ substr($_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName() , 'name'),0,50); ?>
</a>
```

Comment: you test this code is not work?

Comment: @Abhishek I have truncated product name but special characters are getting corrupted while truncating product names. Is there any solution to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pure CSS for this, rather on code level, limiting character from code may me a little bad for SEO.

Read the full answer here
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/319927/26733

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tried the code by Kishan Patadia, it works on catalog page but not on home page, shall we need to run upgrade command?